# How to use GIF animation in Android?

Tags: android

I want to use GIF animation in my application.

How can I do this? I have seen [this tutorial](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-animated-gif-example.html), but I did not get any specific solution.

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textColor="#ACC437"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:text="WelCome To This Blog"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <com.androidqa.AnimationView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**View Class**

```
public class AnimationView extends View {
private Movie mMovie;
private long mMovieStart;
private static final boolean DECODE_STREAM = true;
private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int len;
 try {
  while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
   os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
     }
      return os.toByteArray();
      }
     public AnimationView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context,attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
  java.io.InputStream is;
     // YOUR GIF IMAGE Here
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.th_welcome); 
     if (DECODE_STREAM) {
   mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
      } else {
       byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
     mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
         }
            }
      @Override
       public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
         mMovieStart = now;
          }
        if (mMovie != null) {
         int dur = mMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
        dur = 3000;
         }
       int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
      Log.d("", "real time :: " +relTime);
       mMovie.setTime(relTime);
       mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - 200, getHeight()-200);
       invalidate();
           }
           }
              }
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: sir i downlaoded this code from http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-animated-gif-example.html..,but when i tried to import this,it got currupt,what i do i need of an example of gif animation please help me...:(

Comment: What is error you are getting? What do you mean by corrupt ?

Comment: sir corrupt means when i am trying to run it,its giving me error  that your project contains some error ..,but my project has no errors.

Comment: There should be a error in layout files. Check out carefully. It must be not able to get the `com.androidqa.Anim..` package name for the view.

Comment: sir can you give me example of gif animation please.....

Comment: Check out the tutorial http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Comment: thnku so much sir....:)

Comment: First thing i am madam. And if my answer helped you then vote it, i have posted it as answer.

Comment: Up vote for making you able to comment again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an ImageView. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3" android:duration="100" />
    </animation-list>
```

In your layout :

```
 <ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tutorial [How to play animated GIFs in Android?](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/)